# Can I submit (publish) apps to Google Play as a part of my developer services?

Tags: android, google-play, publish

Say I am an Android application developer and I want to (kind of mass) submit apps to Google Play under my own account. Is this possible? Are there limitations on number of apps that can be submitted within a given timeframe?

Answer (score 1):

As of the moment, there is no writing that tells about a limit as to how many apps can be uploaded by a single developer/account. There is also nothing I can find about how often one can submit or update an app to the Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can submit as many apps as you want.

I think there is no any limitations, unless you submit to frequently like 1 app every minute.
They may have some protection for this case, but I'm not sure.